# trying to fill 2 colomns but keep getting "segmentation fault"

Tags: c

still new to algorithms in general, started with c, but stuck with the error segmentation fault couldn't really know whats the exact problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    int i,nb;
    float T[nb][2];
    printf("how many mesures?\n");
    scanf("%d",&nb);
    
    for(i=0;i<nb;i++)
    {
        printf("whats the temperature T%d ?\n",i);
        scanf("%f",&T[i][0]);
        printf("whats the humidity H%d ?\n",i);
        scanf("%f",&T[i][1]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think the value of `nb` is when your program reaches `float T[nb][2];`?

Comment: I wrote a FAQ about this bug here: [How to declare variable-length arrays correctly?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/283440)

Answer (score 2):

This declaration of a variable length array

```
{
    int i,nb;
    float T[nb][2];
```

has undefined behavior because the variable `nb` is not initialized and has an indeterminate value. You have to declare the array after assigning a positive value to the variable `nb`.

```
int main() 
{
    int i,nb;
    printf("how many mesures?\n");
    scanf("%d",&nb);

    float T[nb][2];
    //...
```